# How do I rewrite this while loop without it being a while True loop?

Tags: python, loops

For a class assignment we are supposed to write a function that prompts the user for input, checks that the user inputed a valid integer between the range of lo and hi and returns the result. We have to print the correct prompts in failure cases and use the provided is_int(str) helper function provided. I've written a version that I feel is fairly concise but the professor has said to avoid while True loops. I've rewritten simpler code that used while True for getting user input but I'm a bit stumped here where there are multiple checks how to rewrite this and have it be as simple and easy to read.

Note: I don't know why when I copy the code in the first tab spacing is missing and the while is on the same line as the def which isn't in my code.

```
def ask_int_between(lo, hi):
    while True:
        result = input(f"Please enter a number from {lo} to {hi}:")
        if not is_int(result):
            print(f'''Please try again: I don't know what int "{result}" is.''')
        else:
            resultInt = int(result) #we now know this will work
            if(resultInt < lo):
                print(f'''Please try again: {resultInt} is too low.''')
            elif(resultInt > hi):
                print(f'''Please try again: {resultInt} is too high.''')
            else:
                return resultInt
```

Comment: `return` without `def`?

Comment: Think about what you changed when you rewrote the simpler code. You need to do the same thing here. The loop condition is "when the input is not valid", so you'll need to ask for the input once before the loop begins, and again inside the loop just before it restarts. IMO, it doesn't make any sense to avoid a `while True` in this case because that is the most concise way I can think of, but a professor wants what a professor wants smh.

Comment: I wonder why the professor doesn't like "while True".  This code looks perfectly reasonable.  If you have to, add a variable `done = False`, then change your code to `while not done`, and instead of `return resultInt` set `done = True`.  But seriously, your professor is wrong.

Comment: *Pranav thanks, the problem is that what causes the input not to be valid is 3 things here it's not and integer at all or it IS but its too low or too hi, that's way to much to put in the body of the while check.

*Frank thanks, yeah I had thought of just that.

Comment: Only `while True` is restricted, presumably because *the goal is to use the condition to break the loop*, instead of `break` or `return`. Can you think of a different condition that could be used to break the loop? Hint: what if you had a function that tells you whether `result` is valid after asking for it? Can you write such a function?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
def ask_int_between (low, high) :
number = str (input (f"Please write a number between {low} and {high}.\n"))
while not number.isnumeric () :
    print (f"Sorry, this answer is not a number. Please try again.")
    number = str (input ())
else :
    while int (number) <= low :
        print ("Sorry, that number is too low. Please try again.")
        number = str (input ())
    else :
        while int (number) >= high :
            print ("Sorry, that number is too high. Please try again.")
            number = str (input ())
        else :
            print (number)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be correct... If your professor doesn't want this loop, you can try to do a stupid thing like that (and make the code shorter) :

```
def ask_int_between(lo, hi):
    done = False
    while not done:
        result = input(f"Please enter a number from {lo} to {hi}:")
        
        if not is_int(result):
            print(f'''Please try again: I don't know what int "{result}" is.''')
        
        else:
            resultInt = int(result) #we now know this will work
            if (resultInt < lo) or (resultInt > hi):
                print(f'''Please try again: {resultInt} is outside the range.''')

            else:
                done = True
                return resultInt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def ok(lo, hi, rv):
    result = input(f'Please enter a number from {lo} to {hi}: ')
    if not is_int(result):
        rv[0] = f"Please try again: I don't know what int {result!r} is."
        return False
    resultInt = int(result)
    if resultInt < lo:
        rv[0] = f'Please try again: {resultInt} is too low.'
        return False
    if resultInt > hi:
        rv[0] = f'Please try again: {resultInt} is too high.'
        return False
    rv[0] = resultInt
    return True

    
def ask_int_between(lo, hi):
    rv = [None]
    while not ok(lo, hi, rv):
        print(rv[0])
    print(rv[0])


def is_int(s):
    try:
        int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


ask_int_between(0, 3)
```

then

```
Please enter a number from 0 to 3: a
Please try again: I don't know what int 'a' is.
Please enter a number from 0 to 3: 4
Please try again: 4 is too high.
Please enter a number from 0 to 3: -1
Please try again: -1 is too low.
Please enter a number from 0 to 3: 0
0
```